# Slow SQL query using "SELECT TOP" generated by Linq Take()

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm having a performance problem with a simple linq query :

```
var query = ctx.Set<AdministrativeProfile>().OrderBy(x => x.User.Lastname).Skip(9000).Take(1);
```

The generated SQL is as follow:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Join1].[ProfileID] AS [ProfileID], 
    [Join1].[Address] AS [Address], 
    [Join1].[BankAccountNumber] AS [BankAccountNumber], 
    [Join1].[BankAccountType] AS [BankAccountType], 
    [Join1].[BankBIC] AS [BankBIC], 
    [Join1].[BankIBAN] AS [BankIBAN], 
    [Join1].[BankName] AS [BankName], 
    [Join1].[City] AS [City], 
    [Join1].[CountryISO] AS [CountryISO], 
    [Join1].[IdentifiedUserID1] AS [IdentifiedUserID], 
    [Join1].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
    [Join1].[SocialSecurityID] AS [SocialSecurityID], 
    [Join1].[WithHoldingTaxRate] AS [WithHoldingTaxRate], 
    [Join1].[Zip] AS [Zip]
    FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[ProfileID] AS [ProfileID], [Extent1].[Address] AS [Address], [Extent1].[BankAccountNumber] AS [BankAccountNumber], [Extent1].[BankAccountType] AS [BankAccountType], [Extent1].[BankBIC] AS [BankBIC], [Extent1].[BankIBAN] AS [BankIBAN], [Extent1].[BankName] AS [BankName], [Extent1].[City] AS [City], [Extent1].[CountryISO] AS [CountryISO], [Extent1].[IdentifiedUserID] AS [IdentifiedUserID1], [Extent1].[Phone] AS [Phone], [Extent1].[SocialSecurityID] AS [SocialSecurityID], [Extent1].[WithHoldingTaxRate] AS [WithHoldingTaxRate], [Extent1].[Zip] AS [Zip], [Extent2].[Lastname] AS [Lastname], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent2].[Lastname] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM  [dbo].[AdministrativeProfile] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[vUsers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IdentifiedUserID] = [Extent2].[IdentifiedUserId]
    )  AS [Join1]
    WHERE [Join1].[row_number] > 9000
    ORDER BY [Join1].[Lastname] ASC
```

The running time for this query is approximately 15 seconds.
I read a few things about `SELECT TOP` being slow because of some kind of sort, but I couldn't manage to find a solution to my problem.

Here's the execution plan
[image: Execution plan]
Few things to note :

1) The `.Skip(n).Take(x)` is added generically by a paging system, so the only part that I could modify without breaking the generic paging is this :

```
ctx.Set<AdministrativeProfile>().OrderBy(x => x.User.Lastname)
```

2) I found a few ways to fix the SQL statement and make it lightning fast (like use `INNER HASH JOIN` in the sub query, or add an additional where clause checking if `[Join1].[row_number] < x`), but since it is generated by a linq query, it doesn't help me much

3) When doing `Skip(x)` with a small number for `x`, it runs much quicker. The execution time increase with how big `x` is.

4) The tables I use do not have many rows. About 9000 each.

So basically, I know how to fix the SQL, but I don't know how to change the linq query to optimize it.

Comment: "I found a few ways to fix the SQL statement and make it lightning fast" - Then why not put the SQL in a stored procedure and call that instead of using LINQ?  LINQ/Hibernate/etc. are all fine and good, until they're not. That's why at the end of the day, straight SQL in an SP is the best option. You can still use entity framework or whatever you're using to call SP's.

Comment: Could you post your SQL solutions?

Comment: You should use a View, when you want to manipulate queries but still have it feel like you are dealing with tables

Comment: @dcp : Because we have generic ways of adding filters / sort parameters to our linq queries, as well as the pagination system. If we have to write a stored procedure for each query, it would take much more time. I could do it for this particular query, but if we run into another query that has the same problem, I prefer to find a way to fix it and use linq everywhere, rather than having some queries using linq, and others using SP. Thanks for the answer though, that's probably what I will do if we can't fix this linq query.

Comment: @Dennis I explained the sql solutions in point 2), I just didn't want to re-paste the whole corrected SQL statement to avoid big chunk of text. Replacing the `INNER JOIN` by `INNER HASH JOIN` in the subquery fixes it, aswell as adding a condition `[Join1].[row_number] < x`

Comment: Generic approaches shouldn't take precedence over approaches that work. It'll always be a matter of finding the golden "best case" approach, but best case is not every case

Comment: @ViviKFF: what EF version and SQL Server version are you using? It's rather simple query... For the curiosity, I've made a sample application using EF 6.1.3 and MSSQL 2012, and I see totally different query, which executes *very* fast.

Comment: What is the relation between AdministrativeUser and AdministrativeProfile - 1.. many? Are you sure ordering by LastName is deterministic?

Comment: Just don't do that Linq query. It's inappropriate. You want the 9000th account in order of lastname? No you don't. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm guessing you are paging through accounts in order of lastname, and this is what happens on later pages. But the real answer is if you mostly order by lastname, put lastname at the front of the clustered index. No rule says clustered index has to be on the PK.

Comment: And don't page through all the accounts. Give the user a search box.

Comment: @Ben I think you are right, it doesn't make much sense to list all accounts, a search box is the way to go. But I am wondering how we would fix this kind of problem if it happens in another scenario. Maybe I'm just being pessimistic, thinking it would happen more often that it will.

Comment: `ctx.Set<User>().OrderBy(x=>x.LastName).Skip(9000).Take(1).Map(x=>x.AdministrativeProfile);`

Answer (score 0):

You should profile the query and see where the bottleneck is. However, I have dealt with a similar problem, and the slowness should be alleviated by adding a [non-clustered index](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp) to the property by which you sort (`[Lastname]` in your case).

Basically speaking: the more members you have to skip, the more sorting has to be performed: the sorting becomes much quicker when using an index.